# Angular 2 view not responding after navigate

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have an api driven app using angular 2. I created a global service extending angular2-sails which, if the response to a call is `401 PLEASE_LOGIN`, redirect the user to the signup component.

The problem is that when I redirect to signup component, the view (which load correctly tho) doesn't respond to user actions. There is no error, the components methods are calling and work when I, for example, click a button, but the view just doesn't react or update.

My setup is the following : My home component template has a reference to a user-sidebar.component. This sidebar component has an ngOnInit method who ask the backend for the authenticated user. When there is no authenticated user, the service who load it redirect to /signup

My user-sidebar.component ngOnInit method :

```
ngOnInit(): void 
{
    this._authService
        .me()
        .subscribe(
            (resData: Object) => { this.user = resData.data; },
            (err: any) => { console.log(err); }
        );
}
```

The AuthService .me() method

```
me(): any 
{
    return this._appService.get('/me');
}
```

My app.service get method :

```
get(path: string, data: Object): Observable
{
    return this._sailsService.get(path, data)
        .catch(this.handleError.bind(this));
}

public handleError(err: Response): void
{
    // If the server response with unhautorized, redirect to login / signup page
    if(err.statusCode == 401 && err.error == 'PLEASE_LOGIN')
    { 
        this._router.navigate(['/signup']);
    }

    return Observable.throw(err);
}
```

Not sure if an angular bug or my code, but my research gave nothing.

Comment: What happens if you return `Observable.of(null)` instead of `Observable.of(err)`?

Comment: The subscribe onError callback receive null instead of the error. But for my current problem, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Ok, didn't fully understand your code previously. You could try to inject `private zone:NgZone` and run `this.zone.run(() => this._router.navigate(['/signup']));` to ensure the problem is not related to change detection not happening.

Comment: The sadness when you solve your problem without understanding what your doing... Joke aside, it worked, thanks mate. Can you post an answer where you explain a bit the solution so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems change detection doesn't work

You can invoke change detection manually using

```
constructor(private zone:NgZone) {}
```

and run

```
this.zone.run(() => this._router.navigate(['/signup']));
```

Actually, I don't know why change detection isn't invoked automatically though.
It might be because `router.navigate` is called in an error handler but I don't see a good reason why this would cause it.

Comment: after several hours found the solution

Comment: Angular can be so unpredictable sometimes. I was struggling with the same thing for the past 2 hours. Just curious though. Can there be some underlying issues because of which angular is not detecting changes?

Comment: If the change is csused by code that runs outside Angulars zone

Comment: I just got hit by the same problem after upgrading angular minor/sone/rxjs version (code with old libs ran fine). I wish I only wasted 2 hours on this, but must admit it has been the better part of two days:-(. Anyways: Thanks an epic bunch for this answer.